# Why Asymptotic Equipartition Property theorem proofs assume the source is memoryless?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, markov-process, information-theory, ergodic

I do not understand the assumption 1,2,⋯ are i.i.d. ~p(x) in the AEP proofs I have seen. I have read some different sources for understanding the Asymptotic Equipartition Property. Using Cover & Thomas [1](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46739/why-asymptotic-equipartition-property-theorem-proofs-assume-the-source-is-memory) as an example (page 51):

Theorem 3.1.1.(AEP): If 1,2,⋯ are i.i.d. ~p(x), then (...)

The proof is by using the weak law of large numbers and the fact that a statistic of independent random variables is also a random variable.

Shannon defines a Source X as an ergodic Markov chain of order k, therefore in the message ()=(1,2...),  are not independent. The aforementioned AEP proof assumes a memoryless Markov chain. Why?

Why this proof of AEP holds for a source that is an ergodic Markov chain?

(This same question was [posted](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46739/why-asymptotic-equipartition-property-theorem-proofs-assume-the-source-is-memory) at cstheory.stackexchange, I do not know which exchange is best suited for this kind of question.)

[1](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46739/why-asymptotic-equipartition-property-theorem-proofs-assume-the-source-is-memory)T. M. Cover and Joy A. Thomas. Elements of Information Theory. 2nd ed. OCLC: ocm59879802. Wiley-Interscience, 2006. isbn: 9780-471-2419-5-9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was answered in depth here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46739/why-asymptotic-equipartition-property-theorem-proofs-assume-the-source-is-memory/46753#46753

I also noticed later that in the end of the chapter, Cover and Thomas add an historical note where they say that in the original 48 proof Shannon used i.i.d. but later, McMillian proved for ergodic markov chains.